# Execute a shell command/script using puppet

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I want to execute a shell command/script using puppet only when a file exists in particular path.

For example if a text file `test.txt` exists in `/root` path then puppet will execute shell script, otherwise puppet didn't execute any commands

Comment: What part of [the documentation for the `Exec` resource type](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec) confuses you in this regard?

Answer (score 4):

You should have done a little research before posting this question. But nevermind..

```
exec {"Comment to your resource":
command => 'your command',
provider => shell,
onlyif => '/usr/bin/test -e /path/to/file/test.txt',
}
```

`onlyif` will execute the command in `Exec` if and only if the command executed(in the `onlyif`) has return code 0.

Comment: NMDV, but do not encourage poor questions by writing answers.

Comment: @JohnBollinger In that case down-vote the question, flag the question or edit it to make it better. Don't go on down-voting correct answers just because you can.

Comment: As I said, Not My DownVote (on your answer).  For what it's worth, I *did* downvote the question, as is called for for one that shows complete absence of research effort; someone else has upvoted it for no apparent reason.  I'm just suggesting a possible reason for the downvote on your answer, regardless of whether it was strictly-speaking appropriate.  And you can expect sometimes to collect such DVs if you choose to answer bad questions.